# Water Dispenser Cooling System

Tags: cooling, heat-exchanger, water-resources, product-engineering

I am interested in creating a water dispenser myself for cooling water, and am looking for a cheap and not too engineering complex concept. I found a water dispenser on Aliexpress, for a very cheap price, and am wondering whether you know how the cooling system works?
Link to the water dispenser: https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005002611932877.html
The water dispenser looks like this:

[image: Water Dispenser at 550 W rated power]

Is it a small refrigeration cycle, or does it contain Peltier elements? If someone would know that would help me out greatly. How is it possible to actually make a working cold water dispenser as cheap as this? Of course I don't know how well it cools the water and to what temperature, but still.

Thank you very much for your answers!

FBMeca

N.B. Not entirely sure in which community this post fits best, feel free to move it if it's misplaced here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This device only heats. The "cold" water is at room temperature. Check this alternative website:[link](https://ma2030.com/Home-Appliances/dmwd-550w-household-electric-water-dispenser-desktop-water-heater-mini-water-boiler-drinking-fountain-constant-temperature-95%E2%84%83/)  It gives this info: "room temperature and heating"

You can see there a picture of the "dual temperature control" which is only  two thermostats for hot water temp - which is usual. One for control, one for safety.

Warm and hot refer to the two water temperatures available -no cold.

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed true. What I meant to say is what does this system use as a heating system (and which I could then maybe subsequently use for a cooling system)? Would you know that?

Comment: It will be like a low powered electric kettle with, hopefully, a reliable thermostat to switch off the heating element when the water gets hot enough. Can you think of any way to use an electric kettle to chill water?

Comment: @Johmi `What I meant to say is what does this system use as a heating system` ... your question does not say that ... please use the edit button to update your question